# Debug vs Release

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#pragma optimize("", off)

DG704API_API bool DIG704IsUSBEx(IN BYTE rack)
{
volatile bool retVal(true);

  try
  {
    // Validate rack
    if ((rack < 1) || (rack > gpData.num70X))
    {
      OutputDebugMsg(DBG_ERROR_LEVEL, "DIG704IsUSBEx: rack out of hardware range");
      throw (ERROR_INVALID_RACK);  // Throw rack error
    }

    // The DIG-704s should always be first in the list
    if (rack <= ((BYTE)gpData.num704))
      retVal = false;               // We are a DIG-704 so return false

    if (retVal)
      OutputDebugMsg(DBG_INFO_LEVEL, "Rack %d is a DIG-705", rack);
    else
      OutputDebugMsg(DBG_INFO_LEVEL, "Rack %d is a DIG-704", rack);
  }
  catch(int error)
  {
    retVal = false;
  }

  return (retVal);
}

#pragma optimize("", on)
```

In Debug Mode if the card is a DIG-704 it returns false.  In Release Mode if the card is a DIG-704 it returns true.

In the software/hardware that I am using I have one DIG-704.
rack = 1
gpData.num704 = 1

It should return false, but when I look at the value returned it is true and when I step through the code it skips over the line retVal = false;   There is no exception being thrown.

gpData is a data structure that is effectively global to the entire program.  num704 is declared as an int.

My first guess was that the code was being optimized out so I tried to turn off optimizations, but adding the #pragma and volatile had no affect.

I'm at a loss as to what to try next.

Comment: My first guess would be initialization. In debug mode the memory is filled with a value. In release it is not and should be considered random garbage values (although the OS will likely zero all new memory added to your process which is very different from the debug fill). However there could be many other debug versus release differences.

Comment: Lacking both necessary `#include`s and some explanation of what kind of environment we're talking about. From the CamelCase and the liberal application of `#pragma` I suspect VisualStudio, and I guess DIG-704 refers to hardware of some kind?

Comment: What is `volatile bool retVal(true);`?

Comment: What toolchain are you using?  Have you compared the assembly for `DIG704IsUSBEx` with and without optimizations?  Is `gpData` marked `volatile`?

Comment: I believe for any help that does not include guessing you will have to include more code context. I expect we would not have access to whatever hardware you are using but I don't think the amount of code presented is enough.

Comment: I am using VisualStudio.  DIG-704 and DIG-705 are hardware that we create.  When the code loads it queries the operating system/drivers about how many of each type are installed.  I tried adding volatile to gpData, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with the function.  The problem was with the Pascal code that was calling the function.  For a function declaration I had:

Function DIG704IsUSBEx(rack: BYTE): Bool; cdecl; External 'DG704API.dll';

It needed to be:

Function DIG704IsUSBEx(rack: BYTE): Boolean; cdecl; External 'DG704API.dll';

I guess that I didn't include enough information for anybody to answer the question.  I tried my best and I didn't think Pascal was the problem because when I stepped through the function in Release mode I saw it just skip over the code.

Thank you to everybody who tried to help.